# Populate list of counties drop down after selecting country

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have an old  old JavaScript code that should allow a user to select a country first to then activate the counties list for that country option. On load the option of the country says ANY and the option to the counties label should say select Choose a country first but it doesn't. Only if a user selects a country first and then going back to select ANY, the select a county first condition appears.

I am not good at all with JavaScript, not mention jQuery. How to correct the existing js or even achieve what I want with much better lean code?

Thank you for your help in advance.

```
<div>
  <label id="country">Country of birth:</label>
  <select name="country"  tabindex="7" onchange="populateCountiesDropdown(this[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="">Any</option>
    <option value="ENGLAND">England</option>
    <option value="IRELAND">Ireland</option>
    <option value="SCOTLAND">Scotland</option>
    <option value="WALES">Wales</option>
  </select>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        setSelect(document.main.country, '');
</script> 
</div>
<div>
  <label id="county">County of birth:</label>
  <select name="county"  tabindex="8">
  </select>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    populateCountiesDropdown(document.main.country.value);
    setSelect(document.main.county, "");
</script> 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counties_dropdown = new Array(); 

        counties_dropdown["ENG"] = new Array("   |All counties in country" ,"BDF|Bedfordshire","BRK|Berkshire","BKM|Buckinghamshire","CAM|Cambridgeshire","CHI|Channel Islands","CHS|Cheshire","CON|Cornwall","CUL|Cumberland","DBY|Derbyshire","DEV|Devon","DOR|Dorset","DUR|Durham","ESS|Essex","GLS|Gloucestershire","HAM|Hampshire","HEF|Herefordshire","HRT|Hertfordshire","HUN|Huntingdonshire","IOM|Isle of Man","KEN|Kent","LAN|Lancashire","LEI|Leicestershire","LIN|Lincolnshire","LND|London","MDX|Middlesex","NFK|Norfolk","NTH|Northamptonshire","NBL|Northumberland","NTT|Nottinghamshire","OXF|Oxfordshire","RUT|Rutlandshire","SAL|Shropshire","SOM|Somerset","STS|Staffordshire","SFK|Suffolk","SRY|Surrey","SSX|Sussex","WAR|Warwickshire","WES|Westmorland","WIL|Wiltshire","WOR|Worcestershire","YKS|Yorkshire" );

        counties_dropdown["IRL"] = new Array("   |All counties in country" ,"ANT|Antrim","ARM|Armagh","CAR|Carlow","CAV|Cavan","CLA|Clare","COR|Cork","LDY|Derry (Londonderry)","DON|Donegal","DOW|Down","DUB|Dublin","FER|Fermanagh","GAL|Galway","KER|Kerry","KID|Kildare","KIK|Kilkenny","OFF|Kings (Offaly)","LET|Leitrim","LIM|Limerick","LOG|Longford","LOU|Louth","MAY|Mayo","MEA|Meath","MOG|Monaghan","NAI|Nairnshire","LEX|Queens (Laois)","ROS|Roscommon","SLI|Sligo","TIP|Tipperary","TYR|Tyrone","WAT|Waterford","WEM|Westmeath","WEX|Wexford","WIC|Wicklow" );

        counties_dropdown["SCT"] = new Array("   |All counties in country" ,"ABD|Aberdeenshire","ARL|Argyllshire","AYR|Ayrshire","BAN|Banffshire","BEW|Berwickshire","BUT|Buteshire","CAI|Caithness","CLK|Clackmannanshire","DFS|Dumfriesshire","DNB|Dunbartonshire","FIF|Fife","ANS|Forfarshire (Angus)","ELN|Haddingtonshire (East Lothian)","INV|Invernessshire","KCD|Kincardineshire","KRS|Kinrossshire","KKD|Kirkcudbrightshire","LKS|Lanarkshire","WLN|Linlithgowshire (West Lothian)","MLN|Midlothian","MOR|Morayshire","PEE|Peeblesshire","PER|Perthshire","RFW|Renfrewshire","ROC|Ross and Cromarty","ROX|Roxburghshire","SEL|Selkirkshire","SHI|Shetland Islands","STI|Stirlingshire","SUT|Sutherland","WIG|Wigtownshire" );

        counties_dropdown["WLS"] = new Array("   |All counties in country" ,"AGY|Anglesey","BRE|Brecknockshire","CAE|Caernarvonshire","CGN|Cardiganshire","CMN|Carmarthenshire","DEN|Denbighshire","FLN|Flintshire","GLA|Glamorganshire","MER|Merionethshire","MON|Monmouthshire","MGY|Montgomeryshire","PEM|Pembrokeshire","RAD|Radnorshire" );

    function populateCountiesDropdown(formObj, country) {
        formObj.county.options.length = 0;
        if(country == "") {
            formObj.county.options[0] = new Option('Choose a country first', '');
            return;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < counties_dropdown[country].length; i++) {
            var option = new Option(counties_dropdown[country][i].substr(counties_dropdown[country][i].indexOf('|')+1), 
                                    counties_dropdown[country][i].substr(0,counties_dropdown[country][i].indexOf('|')));
            formObj.county.options[i] = option;
        }
        formObj.county.options[0].value = '';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I haven't really checked this out thoroughly, but I guess your `counties_dropdown` map should have keys with the same values as your options. That is, rather than `ENG`, `IRL`, etc. they should be `ENGLAND`, `IRELAND`, etc... Moreover, there is no jQuery in your code.

Comment: Yes, there is no jQuery at the moment. I was asking if with jQuery I could achieve that easily and with much less code. As for the keys it seem to work fine on the page; when for example you select England, the counties list for England appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, as you suggest in your comment, would certainly make this code easier to read. However, the best optimisation you can make, in my opinion, is in your county data structure: make this a map, rather than an array where items are delimited by pipe characters, that you then have to split. That is:

```
  var counties = {
    'ENGLAND': {
      'BDF': 'Bedfordshire',
      'BRK': 'Berkshire',
      ...
    },
    'IRELAND': {
      'ANT': 'Antrim',
      'ARM': 'Armagh',
      ...
    },
    'SCOTLAND': {
      'ABD': 'Aberdeenshire',
      'ARL': 'Argyllshire',
      ...
    },
    'WALES': {
      'AGY': 'Anglesey',
      'BRE': 'Brecknockshire',
      ...
    }
  };
```

You can now use the key from the country select's value to drive this and populate the county dropdown. To watch for changes on the country, you can use jQuery's `.change()` function.

I would recommend reading the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) documentation and experimenting. You won't progress very far by letting SO users answer your questions! However, that said, here is my working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/pfYEb/

Comment: thanks so much for your help and example. Can I ask what if I have two forms on a page that within I use the country and county fields? A basic tab and an advanced tab. When I switch between them, something seems to be affecting the function. When I only use it once on the page works a treat your example of jQuery.

Comment: My example wasn't a copy-and-paste job; it's supposed to instruct you on how it *could* be done. I don't know your exact circumstances, so I cannot debug your exact problem, but clearly if you have two forms on the same page, you're going to have to modify my example appropriately. The best advice I can give you is to download some decent devtools (Firebug, Chrome DevTools, etc.), read JS docs and experiment. If you still can't get it working, post another question on SO with relevant details, the code **you've tried** and any debugger output and someone will steer you in the right direction.

Comment: I did found the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to go about this, but one simple way is to hard code the initial state in HTML, then overwrite it with Javascript when needed.

```
<select name="county"  tabindex="8">
  <option>Choose a country first</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Well I just did that. But still the rest of the county options shows. How do I overwrite and what? Sorry really not familiar with JavaScript.

Comment: See answers by Hakan Hastekin and Xophmeister for JavaScript and jQuery implementations. Note that Hakan's solution actually doesn't require jQuery. Xophmeister makes a good recommendation to read the jQuery API.  Also, the "Getting Started" section in their [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/) page is friendly to beginners.  Another suggestion is that if you are unfamiliar with JavaScript, start by going through a tutorial or introduction to that first.  jQuery is written in JavaScript, so if you start with a basic understanding of JavaScript, then jQuery will make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, added some comments as well. Tested working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counties_dropdown = new Array();
    counties_dropdown["ENG"] = new Array("   |All counties in country", "BDF|Bedfordshire", "BRK|Berkshire", "BKM|Buckinghamshire", "CAM|Cambridgeshire", "CHI|Channel Islands", "CHS|Cheshire", "CON|Cornwall", "CUL|Cumberland", "DBY|Derbyshire", "DEV|Devon", "DOR|Dorset", "DUR|Durham", "ESS|Essex", "GLS|Gloucestershire", "HAM|Hampshire", "HEF|Herefordshire", "HRT|Hertfordshire", "HUN|Huntingdonshire", "IOM|Isle of Man", "KEN|Kent", "LAN|Lancashire", "LEI|Leicestershire", "LIN|Lincolnshire", "LND|London", "MDX|Middlesex", "NFK|Norfolk", "NTH|Northamptonshire", "NBL|Northumberland", "NTT|Nottinghamshire", "OXF|Oxfordshire", "RUT|Rutlandshire", "SAL|Shropshire", "SOM|Somerset", "STS|Staffordshire", "SFK|Suffolk", "SRY|Surrey", "SSX|Sussex", "WAR|Warwickshire", "WES|Westmorland", "WIL|Wiltshire", "WOR|Worcestershire", "YKS|Yorkshire");
    counties_dropdown["IRL"] = new Array("   |All counties in country", "ANT|Antrim", "ARM|Armagh", "CAR|Carlow", "CAV|Cavan", "CLA|Clare", "COR|Cork", "LDY|Derry (Londonderry)", "DON|Donegal", "DOW|Down", "DUB|Dublin", "FER|Fermanagh", "GAL|Galway", "KER|Kerry", "KID|Kildare", "KIK|Kilkenny", "OFF|Kings (Offaly)", "LET|Leitrim", "LIM|Limerick", "LOG|Longford", "LOU|Louth", "MAY|Mayo", "MEA|Meath", "MOG|Monaghan", "NAI|Nairnshire", "LEX|Queens (Laois)", "ROS|Roscommon", "SLI|Sligo", "TIP|Tipperary", "TYR|Tyrone", "WAT|Waterford", "WEM|Westmeath", "WEX|Wexford", "WIC|Wicklow");
    counties_dropdown["SCT"] = new Array("   |All counties in country", "ABD|Aberdeenshire", "ARL|Argyllshire", "AYR|Ayrshire", "BAN|Banffshire", "BEW|Berwickshire", "BUT|Buteshire", "CAI|Caithness", "CLK|Clackmannanshire", "DFS|Dumfriesshire", "DNB|Dunbartonshire", "FIF|Fife", "ANS|Forfarshire (Angus)", "ELN|Haddingtonshire (East Lothian)", "INV|Invernessshire", "KCD|Kincardineshire", "KRS|Kinrossshire", "KKD|Kirkcudbrightshire", "LKS|Lanarkshire", "WLN|Linlithgowshire (West Lothian)", "MLN|Midlothian", "MOR|Morayshire", "PEE|Peeblesshire", "PER|Perthshire", "RFW|Renfrewshire", "ROC|Ross and Cromarty", "ROX|Roxburghshire", "SEL|Selkirkshire", "SHI|Shetland Islands", "STI|Stirlingshire", "SUT|Sutherland", "WIG|Wigtownshire");
    counties_dropdown["WLS"] = new Array("   |All counties in country", "AGY|Anglesey", "BRE|Brecknockshire", "CAE|Caernarvonshire", "CGN|Cardiganshire", "CMN|Carmarthenshire", "DEN|Denbighshire", "FLN|Flintshire", "GLA|Glamorganshire", "MER|Merionethshire", "MON|Monmouthshire", "MGY|Montgomeryshire", "PEM|Pembrokeshire", "RAD|Radnorshire");

    function populateCountiesDropdown(country) {
        // get the html element
        var select = document.getElementById("county");

        // remove all options from select
        select.options.length = 0;

        if (country == "") {
            select.options[0] = new Option('Choose a country first', '');
            return;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < counties_dropdown[country].length; i++) {

            // split the element of county array
            // for example after split county array will contain
            // county[0] = 'BDF',
            // county[1] = 'Bedfordshire',
            var county = counties_dropdown[country][i].split('|');

            // add a new option to the select by inserting it to the index of length
            // note that length is zero based, so current length would be the index that you need to
            // add the new option.
            select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(county[1], county[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
<div>
    <label for="country">Country of birth:</label>
    <select id="country" name="country" tabindex="7" onchange="populateCountiesDropdown(this[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Any</option>
        <option value="ENG">England</option>
        <option value="IRL">Ireland</option>
        <option value="SCT">Scotland</option>
        <option value="WLS">Wales</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="county">County of birth:</label>
    <select id="county">
        <option value=""> Choose a country first</option>
    </select>
</div>
```